# Recording Audio in a Java Applet (Policy File Options)

Tags: java, applet, same-origin-policy

I built a quick applet to record audio and send the audio to a server.  Everything works great with exception of the policy file issues.  I can't very well have users open up the policy tool and edit the permissions for applets, as I'm sure that would turn off 100/100 users.  Are there any options anyone can think to get around it?  Is there a way to have the applet prompt them for acceptance like in Flash?

PS It's a Node.JS server.  How funny, a Java client talking to a JavaScript server :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have the applet prompt them for acceptance..

Digitally sign the applet code.  See [Signing and Verifying JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html) for more details.

> Don't they (the end user) have to import the key to their keystore?

Short answer, no.  Long answer, the end user only has to click 'OK/Yes' when prompted to trust the digitally signed code, and whatever importing may be required happens automatically.

Try the trusted version of the [file service demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) for a taste of how it might be for the end user (i.e. 'easy').

Comment: Don't they have to import the key to their keystore?  That's a deal breaker.